# FATAL: role "des0071" does not exist in postgis ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, postgis

Use postgis as a adapter
My database.yml is

```
 development:
  adapter: postgis
  database: looks
  timeout: 5000
```

When I run rake db:create it gives me an error.

```
FATAL: role "des0071" does not exist in postgis ruby on rails
```

But USERNAME and Password exist 
Username: postgres
Password: root

Comment: why `postgis` as `adapter` instead of `postgres`, using any gem?

Comment: Have you tried to specifically specify to use the provided username and password from inside your `database.yml` file? `username: postgres password: root' Just like you said?

Comment: Because its must fot postgis

Comment: Yes but it still give this error

Comment: All you have in your `database.yml` is database name and timeout. No login, password or host. What are you expecting then? :] Edit the question to reflect **the best** of what you've attempted to do.